# "Select a valid choice" error only on first submission try using django-autocomplete-light

Tags: django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I'm getting this weird error using django-autocomplete-light: "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." However, if I stay on the same page and just push Submit again it submits the form no problem, and the data in the form is inserted in the database like it should.

I have an embedded form with addable inlines from another Model. With these models I can make a BookSubmission having multiple different Books (pointed to another Book Models through ForeignKey) on the same BookSumbission page and for every Book their Quantity specified.

When I don't have the widget activated everything works fine. I can select one or more Books from the expected list. 
If activate the widget, everything seems to work fine, even the widget shows the expected Books. However, if I push submit I get the error. Push submit again and the form submits flawlessly.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? I thought maybe it has something to do with the load order of the .js files, but playing around with it haven't given me any fruitless results.

models.py

```
class BookSubmission(models.Model):
    SubmissionTitle = models.CharField(
                                     max_length=6,
                                     verbose_name="Submission Title",
                                     unique=True)
    SubmissionText = models.TextField(
                                    max_length=1500,
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    verbose_name="Submission Text"
                                    )


class BooksAndQuantity(models.Model):
    Submission = models.ForeignKey(
                                   'Submission',
                                   null=True,
                                   blank=True,
                                   verbose_name="BookSubmission"
                                   )
    Book = models.ForeignKey(
                                 'Books',
                                 to_field='BookTitle',
                                 db_column='BookTitleID',
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 )
    Quantity = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Quantity")


class Books(models.Model):
    BookTitle = models.CharField(
                                   max_length=6,
                                   unique=True,
                                   db_column='BookTitleID')
    BookText = models.TextField(
                                  max_length=1500,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True
                                  )
```

forms.py

```
class BookSubmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookSubmission
        fields = '__all__'

BookAndQuantityFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    BookSubmission,
    BookAndQuantity,
    fields='__all__',
    extra=1,
    widgets={'Book':
             autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='BookAutocomplete')})
```

views.py

```
class BookSubmissionView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'BookSubmission.html'
    model = BookSubmission
    form_class = BookSubmissionForm
    success_url = 'success/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles GET requests and instantiates blank versions of the form
        and its inline formsets.
        """
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        BookAndQuantityForm = BookAndQuantityFormset()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  BookAndQuantityForm=BookAndQuantityForm))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance and its inline
        formsets with the passed POST variables and then checking them for
        validity.
        """
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        BookAndQuantityForm = BookAndQuantityFormset(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and BookAndQuantityForm.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, BookAndQuantityForm)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, BookAndQuantityForm)

    def form_valid(self, form, BookAndQuantityForm):
        """
        Called if all forms are valid. Creates a Recipe instance along with
        associated Ingredients and Instructions and then redirects to a
        success page.
        """
        self.object = form.save()
        BookAndQuantityForm.instance = self.object
        BookAndQuantityForm.save()
        specieandquantityout_form.instance = self.object
        specieandquantityout_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, BookAndQuantityForm):
        """
        Called if a form is invalid. Re-renders the context data with the
        data-filled forms and errors.
        """
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  BookAndQuantityForm=BookAndQuantityForm))


class BookAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
        # if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        #    return Specie.objects.none()

        qs = Books.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(BookTitle__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

With the following html files:

parent.html

```
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/navbar-fixed-top.css' %}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/assets/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css' %}" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="{% static 'personal/assets/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'personal/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
          height:100%
        }
    </style>

</head>
```

BookSubmission.html

```
{% extends "parent.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h1>Add BookSubmissionForm</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <p> BookSubmission Title {{ form.SubmissionTitle }} </p>
                <p> BookSubmission Text {{ form.SubmissionText }} </p>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Book and Quantity</legend>
                {{ bookandquantity_form.management_form }}
                {{ bookandquantity_form.non_form_errors }}
                {% for form in bookandquantity_form %}
                    {{ form.id }}

                    <div class="inline {{ bookandquantity_form.prefix }}">
                        {{ form.Book.errors }}
                        {{ form.Book.label_tag }}
                        {{ form.Book }}
                        {{ form.Quantity.errors }}
                        {{ form.Quantity.label_tag }}
                        {{ form.Quantity }}
                    </div>
                {{ form.media }}
                {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Add BookSubmission" class="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block footerContent %}
    <script src="{% static 'MM/js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".inline.{{ bookandquantity_form.prefix }}").formset({
                prefix: "{{ bookandquantity_form.prefix }}",
            })
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^BookAutoComplete/$',
    views.BookAutoComplete.as_view(),
    name='BookAutoComplete'),
```

*edit*

What else is weird is the following, the first time that i push "Add another" in the form it looks bugged.
In the following picture the same Formset is inserted twice (now named "Species and Quanity" In & Out).

"Species and Quantity In" is depicted without clicking "Add Another"
In "Species and Quantity Out" I did click on "Add Another", and you can see that the first row becomes buggy, and in the second row a blank useless field is added.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDLjS.png)

Comment: Where are the BookAutocomplete url and view defined ?

Comment: `        BookAndQuantityForm = BookAndQuantityFormset(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and BookAndQuantityForm.is_valid():` what is this ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put everything in this post. Added the url and view part.

Comment: I don't exactly know what the is_valid()  part is to be honest.

Comment: Is there any reason create_field is not defined in the view ? http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/tutorial.html#creation-of-new-choices-in-the-autocomplete-form

Comment: Hey jpic,
I have added the "create_field='name'" to the urls.py, between the parentheses. The "Add New Item" shows up in the choices, but I cannot click it.
Another thing I see now is that only the first two instances of the form are clickable, three or later are not clickable (this problem is also without the "create_field" addition).

Answer (score 0):

Your form validation code is wrong, that's why the form doesn't validate.

Try without the autocomplete widget if in doubt.

See [Django forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) for details.

Comment: Alright. I'll dive into it next week and get back to you. Thanks!